# Adicionar class numa DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, table, datatable

Estou fazendo alterações em uma `pagina.aspx` de um sistema, no entanto muitas coisas são geradas através de funções da linguagem.

Como não dá para adicionar uma class via código, estou tentando adicionar via jQuery, mas não estou conseguindo, abaixo vai um exemplo de um trecho do código.

```
<table id="ctl19_tableAreas" style="height:100%;width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:249px;">
            <td style="width:33%;padding-top:20px;" valign="top">
            </td>

            <td style="width:33%;padding-top:20px;" valign="top">
            </td>

            <td style="width:33%;padding-top:20px;" valign="top">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Então minha pergunta é como faço para adicionar uma classe nessas colunas:

```
style=width:33%;
padding-top:20px;
valign=top
```

Não pode ser para todas pois dentro de cada uma tem outras tabelas, uma confusão total.

Comment: `$('#ctl19_tableAreas td').addClass('a_tua_classe');` deve chegar para adicionares a classe. Podes explicar melhor porque precisas da classe e o que queres fazer? e junta também o jQuery para percebermos melhor o contexto.

Comment: Eu ja fiz isso, o problema é que isso irá adicionar a class em todas as td, e dentro das td existe outras tabelas.
Preciso adicionar essa class para poder conseguir formatar 4 colunas via css

Comment: Se usares `'#ctl19_tableAreas > tbody > tr > td'` no seletor isso só irá selecionar as `td`de "1a geração" e não as de outras tabelas dentro dessa primeira. É isso que queres?

Comment: Acho bem viável a resposta do @PedroCamaraJunior

Comment: Exatamente isto vou, testar a solução de um colega postou abaixo

Comment: Sergio, funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [seletor child](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) do jQuery

```js
$("table#ctl19_tableAreas tr>td").addClass("myClass");
```

```css
.myClass {
  width: 33%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="ctl19_tableAreas" style="height:100%;width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        a
      </td>

      <td>
        b
      </td>

      <td>
        c
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o seletor `>` que indica descendência imediata. Por exemplo `#ctl19_tableAreas td` irá selecionar todas as `td` dentro dessa tabela com id `ctl19_tableAreas` mas também tabelas dentro dessa tabela.

Porém usando `'#ctl19_tableAreas > tbody > tr > td'` garante que somente `td` descendentes da primeira tabela sejam selecionados.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais eficiente e usando a própria biblioteca do datatable. O número representa a coluna da tabela, lembrando que a contagem começa com 0.

```
columnDefs: [
    { className: "td-actions text-right", "targets": [ 4 ] },
],
```